# How to stop continually overwriting a variable when a button is clicked?

Tags: java, variables, input, event-handling, listener

I am trying to make a simple calculator so that when the + button is pressed it adds two variables together but whenever the listener for the button is called, it resets the variable that I previously wanted stored. How can I get around this?

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{  
    int accumulator1 = 1;

    int userinput;


    if(e.getSource()==input)
    {  
        userinput = Integer.parseInt(input.getText());
        System.out.println(userinput);
    }
    if(e.getSource()==add)
    {
        accumulator1 = userinput + accumulator1;
        System.out.println(accumulator1);
        System.out.println(userinput);
        accumulator.setText(String.valueOf(accumulator1));
    }   
}
```

Comment: You might want to indicate which programming language you are using...

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you just need to take accumulator1 out of the function and give it a global scope.  So you set it to 1 when you first declare it, and `public void actionPerformed` only adds to it without declaring / reinitiating it.  (Unless I'm completely misunderstanding what's going on...!)

Comment: uhm kind off. the problem is actually with userinput. i need to initiallise that globally, but when i try to, public void actionPerformed denies any instance of it!

Comment: hi, yeah just tried that, had to initialise both globally, now works a treat thanks!